# how to subset a data frame based on two consecutive column values in a row in R

Tags: r, subset

I have the following two data frame

> miRNA_expval_uni:

```
          miRNA  Genenames  Pubmed_Id
hsa-miR-181a-5p      DUSP6   17382377
 hsa-miR-20a-5p      HIF1A   18632605
hsa-miR-146a-5p      CXCR4   18568019
hsa-miR-146a-5p      CXCR4   20375304
hsa-miR-200b-3p       RND3   20683643
 hsa-miR-328-3p      PTPRJ   22564856
 hsa-miR-122-5p     CYP7A1   20351063
 hsa-miR-222-3p     STAT5A   20489169
  hsa-miR-21-5p    RASGRP1   20483747
  hsa-miR-21-5p    RASGRP1   18591254
```

> GenemiRNA:

```
Genes             miRNA
RND3     hsa-miR-200b-3p
RASGRP1    hsa-miR-21-5p
PTPRJ     hsa-miR-328-3p
ELK3      hsa-miR-19b-3p
ELK3      hsa-miR-454-3p
ELK3        hsa-miR-301b
ELK3        hsa-miR-4295
ELK3        hsa-miR-3666
```

I want to subset from data frame miRNA_expval_uni where the rows  in GenemiRNA are equal to the rows in miRNA_expval_uni. I have been trying different approaches but none of then works. I tried:

```
set <- rbind(set, GenemiRNA[(GenemiRNA$Genes %in%  
             miRNA_expval_uni$Genenames):(GenemiRNA$miRNA 
             %in% miRNA_expval_uni$miRNA), ])
```

I have also tried using a for loop it still only gets the first values

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Here is my solution, it may not be the most elegant, but it works and only uses the base packages in R.

Get the indicies in GenemiRNA for matching genes in miRNA_expval_uni.

```
idx1 = lapply(miRNA_expval_uni$Genenames,function(x) which(x==GenemiRNA$Genes))
```

Next get the indicies in GenemiRNA for matching miRNA in miRNA_expval_uni.

```
idx2 = sapply(miRNA_expval_uni$miRNA,function(x) which(x==GenemiRNA$miRNA))
```

Now we want to compare the two different sets of indicies to see which rows have a match in both **and** that both matches are to the **same row** in miRNA_expval_uni.

```
result =mapply(intersect,idx1,idx2)
```

Now we just need to clean up the output to get our list of subset indicies.

```
result = sort(unique(unlist(result)))
set = GenemiRNA[result,]
```

Set is the subset of GenemiRNA where the rows in GenemiRNA have an exact match in miRNA_expval_uni. If you want the reverse, just switch the names and corresponding column references in the solution above.

### Test Data

```
miRNA,Genenames,Pubmed_Id
hsa-miR-181a-5p,DUSP6,17382377
hsa-miR-20a-5p,HIF1A,18632605
hsa-miR-146a-5p,CXCR4,18568019
hsa-miR-146a-5p,CXCR4,20375304
hsa-miR-200b-3p,RND3,20683643
hsa-miR-328-3p,PTPRJ,22564856
hsa-miR-122-5p,CYP7A1,20351063
hsa-miR-222-3p,STAT5A,20489169
hsa-miR-21-5p,RASGRP1,20483747
hsa-miR-21-5p,RASGRP1,18591254
hsa-miR-454-3p,ELK3,12345
hsa-miR-221-5p,ELK3,12345
hsa-miR-454-3p,BOB,12345
hsa-miR-3666,BOBBY,12345

Genes,  miRNA
RND3,hsa-miR-200b-3p
RASGRP1,hsa-miR-21-5p
PTPRJ,hsa-miR-328-3p
ELK3,hsa-miR-19b-3p
ELK3,hsa-miR-454-3p
ELK3,hsa-miR-301b
ELK3,hsa-miR-4295
ELK3,hsa-miR-3666
```

### Results

```
Genes           miRNA
1    RND3 hsa-miR-200b-3p
2 RASGRP1   hsa-miR-21-5p
3   PTPRJ  hsa-miR-328-3p
5    ELK3  hsa-miR-454-3p
```

### Note

If you where to use something like the following: `subset(GenemiRNA,(Genes%in%miRNA_expval_uni$Genenames)&(miRNA%in%miRNA_expval_uni$miRNA))` which is basically what you were originally trying, it would fail.  This is because it would return any row whose gene and miRNA had a match in the other data set, but not necessarily **only those with both matches to the same row/position**.  If you where to run this on the test data above, you get:

```
Genes           miRNA
1    RND3 hsa-miR-200b-3p
2 RASGRP1   hsa-miR-21-5p
3   PTPRJ  hsa-miR-328-3p
5    ELK3  hsa-miR-454-3p
8    ELK3    hsa-miR-3666  **INCORRECT MATCH**
```

This is because `ELK3` is in both data sets, as is `hsa-miR-3666`.  However, they are never present in the same row, so the last value in the results table is erronious.  You do not get this error if you use my solution.

## Why your attempts did not work

This problem is actually rather complex, because there can be repeated values in both data sets.  The reason your attempts did not work is because you are using %in% which is really just a call to match(). Below is a snippet from the match() documentation (emphasis mine):

> match returns a vector of the positions of **(first)** matches of its first argument in its second.
>
> %in% is a more intuitive interface as a binary operator, which returns a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left operand.
>
> %in% is currently defined as 
>   "%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0

So calling %in% tells you there is **at least one match** but it does not tell you if there is **more than one match** (same goes for the match function). This is why your approach only returns *"the first values"*, you are only getting the first match, not all the matches.

Thus, the correct approach is to generate a list of all matches in attribute `x` for each row. Then compare each list and find the common elements across all lists for a given row. The row indicies of these common elements are your desired subset indicies.

Have any questions about what I did? Leave a comment below and I will explain the best I can.

**Note:** You many need to read in your data setting stringsAsFactors=FALSE for this to work as sometimes comparing factors can cause 'problems'.

Note2: As some have suggested, you can use the `data.table` package for this as well.  Note that it will combine your data tables, so it does not strictly answer your question (ie. you will get an output merging the data from the two together, so it will contain the `PubMedID` column and both `RASGRP1` entries despite there only being one in `GenemiRNA`)

Note3: While the family of *apply functions are very confusing at first, understand each of them and when/how to use them is VERY useful skill to have.  A great introduction can be found below (I personally found the R documentation to be much too confusing to gain an intuitive understanding of each function)

https://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/

Comment: @sjds If you want to exclude common rows, use `-` on the results ie. `GenemiRNA[-results, ]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to call the first one `A` and second one `B`. Here's a solution using `data.table` package:

```
require(data.table) ## >= 1.9.2
setDT(A) ## convert the data.frame to data.tables by reference
setDT(B)

# set the columns on which you'd want the join to be based on
setkey(A, miRNA, Genenames)
setkey(B, miRNA, Genes)

# join
A[B, nomatch=0L]
#              miRNA Genenames Pubmed_Id
# 1: hsa-miR-200b-3p      RND3  20683643
# 2:   hsa-miR-21-5p   RASGRP1  20483747
# 3:   hsa-miR-21-5p   RASGRP1  18591254
# 4:  hsa-miR-328-3p     PTPRJ  22564856
```

The `nomatch` parameter ensures that only those rows that matches are returned. If you remove it, all rows from `B` are returned, with `NA`s for corresponding `A` columns.

Comment: Hi, I actually have the opposite problem. How can I use match or no match to exclude rows from a second dataframe. I tried ' A[B, nomatch != 0L]` but I get an error "object nomatch not found"...